# php ajax if no data then wait until short before time out

Tags: php, ajax, timeout

I was thinking if it was a good thing to do in this exact situation:

in **chat** application the client send a request every few seconds to server to check if there is new incoming messages. this could be heavy for the server connection.
 so why not setting a relative long the time out request lets say 2 min:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.timeout = 1000 * 120;
```

and on the server side we make our code wait till short before time out or there is new messages:

```
do{
    sleep(5) // 5 seconds
    make the checks () and necessary staff;
    compute no_new_messages;
}while(delay < (1000 * 100) && (no_new_messages))
echo (the requests results)
```

I know this will keep the script longer in memory with other clients requests too, but few kBs may be better managed than doing the request all the time again. and what matters for me here is more the server not the client.

Comment: hello Any yes/no ppl?